# (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord

I don't get what's wrong here? It keeps telling me

> (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

is it because I've put `client.on` event in a command and not in the bot core file? I've tried putting both `client.on` events on there and still when I execute the command it doesn't give me the roles I've configured.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();


module.exports = {
    name: 'games',
    description: "Select the games",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, bot) {
        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('552561546039918593')) {
        const channel = '905072473899409438';
        const gifsRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "GIFS");
        const emojiRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "EMOJIS");
  
        const gifs = ('<:hersheys:823607413843951646>');
        const emoji = ('<:glokez:858101005512867892>');
        const gifsEmoij = ('823607413843951646');
        const emojiEmoij = ('858101005512867892');
  
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('<a:sparkles1:905070246610739240>  **Role Selection**')
            .setDescription(`Choose what roles you want to access!\n\n`
                + `${gifs}   **(**    GIFS                       **)**\n`
                + `${emoji}   **(**    EMOJIS     **)**`);
        
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(gifsEmoij);
        messageEmbed.react(emojiEmoij);
  
        bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
            if (reaction.emoji.id === gifsEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(gifsRole);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.id === emojiEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(emojiRole);
            }
            else {
            return;
        }
  
        });
  
        bot.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
  
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.id === gifsEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(gifsRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.id === emojiEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(emojiRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your file, you create a variable with the identifier `bot`:

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();
```

And in the definition of your `execute` function you define a local variable named 'bot', too:

```
async execute(message, args, Discord, bot) {
```

When you call `execute("Hello World", [], someDiscordClient)`, `bot` will be undefined in your function. It will not 'fall back' to the value in the upper scope. Since undefined hasn't got a property named 'on'—in fact, it has no properties at all—you get "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined".

You probably want to remove `bot` from the list of parameters.

Or, you could do this, if you want the *option* but not *obligation* to set the variable:

```
async execute(message, args, Discord, botInstance = bot) {
     // Use the value given or, if not set, use the fallback.

     // ... rest of your code
     botInstance.on('messageReactionAdd', (etcetera)
```

Comment: alright but I've renamed bot to "client" and added it in the first place since just because  it gives me this error `(node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined` when I'm executing the command in the server.. I mean it still sends the embed and everything but it's not giving me any roles and i don't know why, i've updated the code a lot since, here's the code https://sourceb.in/B66stl6jPT

Comment: You should update your original question (or close this and open a new one)—now that you've fixed the first problem you're running into a very different problem (regarding the usage of Discord's api). You should update the modified code & include some `console.log` statements to help other people know _where_ your problem is.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll open a new one.